# html retaining user history on a webpage

Tags: html, css, browser-history

On a couple of webpages that I have visited, indications of my previous visits are evident, ie links already visited. What html code do I need to implement this function in a page that I am building? Or does it only depend on the history settings?
Thanks.
Dave

Comment: Your question is a bit vague, but maybe you need to set style for `a:visited` in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You may use various soluttions. For example cookies in javascript/php. Or If you just want to know that user vistied a link you can use :visited for example

```
a {color:black;}
a:visited { color: green;}
<a href="#" >link</link>
```

then if user visited link it will be green, if he didn't it then it'll be black.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser knows what pages you have visited.  You don't need to do anything special.

If you want to style links to visited pages, use CSS as follows:

```
a:visited {
    /* your styles*/
}
```

So, for example, if you want your links to be blue and bold normally but grey and not bold when they've been visited, you could do something like this:

```
a {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
a:visited {
    color: gray;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

**Edit:**

I didn't initially include this because I assumed it was obvious, but you did specifically ask about html.  So, in the interest of thoroughness, the html for a link is:

```
<a href="<!-- the target of your link -->">Link text</a>
```

So, a link to Stack Overflow would be:

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Stack Overflow</a>
```

You might want to check out an [HTML / CSS Tutorial](http://learn.shayhowe.com/html-css/) for further help.